# Problems processing duplicate xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a obvious "newbie" question. I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tag1>
    <tag2>data 1</tag2>
    <tag2>data 2</tag2>
</Tag1>
```

And I want to process it with the following xsl file using SaxonHE9:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>  
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="Tag1/tag2"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

data 1

I would like to get both "data 1" and "data 2"

Clearly this is a text case. In my real xml file I have zero to many examples of tag2.

Thanks for helping a new user.

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Otherwise you're in [backwards-compatible](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards) mode, and `xsl:value-of` will return only the value of the first node in the selected set - as it would in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks! That was quick AND simple!